# Why some things left undefined behavior in C++? Wouldn't it be better if some of them pre-defined in the standard?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

I am C++ programmer. While during surfing i became familiar with the terms like undefined behavior, unspecified behavior, implementation defined behavior etc. I am wondering why some things left undefined? I know that C++ is close to hardware but is it really hard to define a behavior for some of them? If so why they didn't do it? This question is about the philosophy behind leaving out so many behaviors open for compiler implementation. I think & believe that there are 2 following advantages of this:

> 1) It allows better performance. It simplifies the job of compiler, making it possible to generate very efficient code in certain situations.
>
> 2) It allows flexibility to compiler vendors to implement it in their own
>    way.

If you know of any other factors other than performance please tell me.
Your help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/99692/philosophy-behind-undefined-behavior

Comment: "The C++ standard should be longer" said nobody ever. That said, although it's a interesting question for sure, I'm not sure it belongs on SO.

Comment: one example: shifting left over the width of the type is undefined behavior, since some CPUs don't mask the shift amount out

Comment: This does not answer the question, but those articles gave me a good read on UB: http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html

Comment: @Serthy: The link you mentioned says about performance. I read that already.

Comment: @meet I thought so, thats why I said it will not answer your Q. However for other readers this might be quite useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the reasons you already mentioned, one important thing is to understand that CPU's differ. They still do, but it used to be worse. Trying to specify exactly how C++ behaves in corner cases is just not helpful. E.g. `0/0` will be handled differently by different CPU's, and it doesn't really matter for real programs.

Another issue is that some UB is hard to detect . For instance, violations of the One Definition Rule across Translation Units would require support in the linker phase, and there's been quite some tolerance for vendors who rely on primitive linkers.

Comment: Historically, "Undefined Behavior" meant "do what would naturally happen on the platform".  If dividing by zero triggered a hardware trap whose vector nobody bothered to set, anything could happen, but on most implementations with a hardware trap one could assume that division by zero would either trigger the trap or have no other consequence (e.g. a compiler which realized the result of division wasn't used might omit it altogether).  Today, however, "Undefined Behavior" is no longer bound by the laws of time and causality.

Comment: Some of today's compilers, if they recognize that Undefined Behavior will be inevitable unless certain conditions apply, will assume that it must apply and omit any code which would only be relevant if those conditions applied.

Answer (score 1):

The design philosophy of C++ doesn't force a choice upon you. If something is limited by architecture then there is a limitation, but otherwise there are very few arbitrary decisions made about semantics where there can be multiple interpretations.

If you look at some cases of undefined behavior - null pointer reference, floating point overflow and so on. The actual behavior of the computer and OS is more or less undefined. You cannot assume whether the hardware will trap or if the OS specific run time will be able to behave in a valid manner when memory errors occur.

We happen to use primarily x86 based machines, with protected mode OSes which all follow POSIX to a reasonable degree. But this was not always true.

There existed some architectures where merely initializing a pointer to an invalid address would cause a hardware trap - you didn't even have to dereference it.

Most cases where undefined behavior exists is because it is *undefined* like 1/0

Comment: Originally, many things were left as Undefined Behavior to allow for the possibility that various implementations might have different "natural" behaviors that programmers might find useful.  Unfortunately, modern compiler philosophy seems to head in a very different direction, such that code which causes Undefined Behavior may be written by the compiler in weird ways that are totally unrelated to anything hardware would "naturally" do (including having the compiler bypass checks which would have allowed code to deal with the "natural" consequences of the behavior).